# How to avoid Rancher RKE Reconcile warning?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rancher-rke, reconcile

Whenever I set up a Rancher Kubernetes cluster with RKE, the cluster sets up perfectly. However, I'm getting the following warning message:

```
WARN[0011] [reconcile] host [host.example.com] is a control plane node without reachable Kubernetes API endpoint in the cluster
WARN[0011] [reconcile] no control plane node with reachable Kubernetes API endpoint in the cluster found
```

*(in the above message, the `host.example.com` is a placeholder for my actual host name, this message is given for each controlplane host specified in the cluster.yml)*

How can I modify the RKE `cluster.yml` file or any other setting to avoid this warning?

Comment: Fisrt - [Check if the Controlplane Containers are Running](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/troubleshooting/kubernetes-components/controlplane/). If it doesn't help please edit your question and add more info: your `cluster.yml` file, when exactly did you have this warning?  See also this similar topic: https://forums.rancher.com/t/rke-on-the-command-line-with-aws-and-ec2/19493/6

Comment: When I first run 'rke up', the controlpane containers are not yet running. It is the 'rke up' which installs everyting, including the controlpane containers. Therefore, at the first run of `rke`, nothing is running yet, so the warning is given.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can suppress this warning since as you indicate in your comments, the warning is valid on the first `rke up` command.  It is only a warning, and a valid one at that, even though your configuration appears to have a handle on that.  If you are worried about the logs, you could perhaps have your log aggregation tool ignore the warning if it is in close proximity to the initial `rke up` command, or even filter it out.  However, I would think twice about filtering blindly on it as it would indicate a potential issue (if, for example, you thought the control plane containers were already running).